# Highlight react components in JSX (WebStorm IDE)

Tags: reactjs, editor, webstorm, syntax-highlighting, jsx

How to configure highlighting of custom/react components in JSX (render block)?

[image: WebStorm React Simple App JSX Example]

I want to configure editor color for `<Home />` component in this example. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not currently possible.
Related feature requests: [WEB-21035](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21035), [WEB-330](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-330)

Answer (score 3):

As of PhpStorm 2022.3 Beta (EAP), the highlighting for React components **differs** from other elements in JSX for most color schemes by default.

This is how it looks in Darcula color scheme that you use:

[image: React component render method code with Darcula color scheme]

And this is how it looks in IntelliJ Light color scheme (my preferred scheme):

[image: React component render method code with IntelliJ Light color scheme]

If you don't like the default color, you can customize it in Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) > Editor > Color Scheme > XML, select "Custom Tag Name" and change the Foreground color:

[image: PhpStorm - Settings - changing the color of React component in JSX]

If Foreground and other options are disabled, you need to uncheck the "Inherit values from:" checkbox below these options.